# Inheritance of auto-implemented property with only getter needed in a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have next code

```
class Base
{
    public virtual int Prop { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override int Prop { get { return 1; } }
}

//...
Derived obj = new Derived();
int some = obj.Prop; //expected
obj.Prop = 10; //oops it works
```

The fact that the last line should complile seems not to be so obvious at first sight. In my program I have a situation when overriding some auto-implemented property in a such way would be a solution. I understand that it's not a good approach. What kind of refactoring can I do to avoid such inheritance and to clean my code? Thanks

Comment: Would making the base class's setter private or protected achieve what you want?

Comment: You could override the `set` accessor as well? You may want to make it throw.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen, I can do this but it doesn't seem to be a clean solution as well.

Comment: why do you say 'I understand that it's not a good approach'?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
    public virtual int Prop { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new int Prop { get { return 1; } private set {}  }
}
```

The problem is that if you cast your Derived to Base, you can set the property anyway. If the Property relay on a field, it will be overwriten.

Ex.:

```
class Base
{
    protected int fProp;
    public virtual int Prop { get { return fProp; } set { fProp = value; } }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        fProp = 1;
    }
    public new int Prop { get { return fProp; } private set {}  }
}



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //...
            Derived obj = new Derived();
            int some = obj.Prop; //expected
            Base b = (Base)obj;
            b.Prop = 10; //oops it works
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Prop); =>it will show 10, not 1
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

A "better" approach to avoid this kind of problem is to avoid the use of a base class if you want to "change" something on a derived class. Or, put only the minimal content that must be implemente by ALL derived classes and let the derived classes implement any extra code that only they want.

Ex:

```
class Base
{
    protected int fProp;
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
    {
        fProp = 1;
    }
    public int Prop { get { return fProp; } }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    public int Prop { get { return fProp; }  set { fProp = value; } }
}



namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //...
            Derived obj = new Derived();
            int some = obj.Prop; //expected
            Base b = (Base)obj;
            //obj.Prop = 10; Compilation error
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Prop);
            Derived2 obj2 = new Derived2();
            obj2.Prop = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(obj2.Prop);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could "encapsulate" your base class:

```
class Derived
{
    protected Base fBase;

    public Derived()
    {
        fBase = new Base;
    }

    //implement enything that you need to access from Base class

    public int Prop { get { return 1; } }
}
```

But I find this last one too "expensive"... :)

Comment: Introducing a `new` member with the same name only leads to more problems. Also, the `private` set accessor only "hides" the `public` on from the base class when it is accessible. From the outside, the `private` accessor is no-go, so calls will go to the `public` on instead, i.e. the `private` one can hide a `public` one only from within the same class.

Comment: Yes, I agree that a "new" member will not avoid confusion and even the changing of the property returning value if the Property relays on a field.

Comment: Did you replace the property by a field within your base-class? Wouldn´t this change the behaviour of the base-class quite much (as you mentioned in my answer)?. Nevertheless you now have two different members, one on the base-class called `fBase` and one on its derived type called `Prop` (which is actually a Property rather then a field). Your first solution however won´t compile at all because you cannot restrict the access of a member on a derived class

Comment: You're wrong @HimBromBeere. In the first suggestion, the Derived.Prop is declared as "new", so it's a new property, hiding the base class one (and it compiles). Also, using a field will not change the behaviour of Prop in the base class. At all. The second example was just to show that you can still access the base Prop and change the value in the Derived class if you use new and relay on a field. This will not change the behaviour of the base class at all, you will just limit the direct access to the data through the derived class (but not through the base class, as is in my answer)

Comment: Indeed I missed your new-keyword (which will lead to more problems as mentioned above). However you actually change the behaviour of `Prop` in base-class (just because Prop does not even exist there) if you use a field rather then a property. This is not obvious on auto-implemented properties on first glance but at least when using reflection you have to consider if your member actually is a field or a property. But that point won´t matter here too much, OP did not state anything...

Comment: @HimBromBeere, when I said "change behaviour", I was talking about a "property" (same name) doing different things on a base class (auto property) and a derived class (throws exception on set). When you CHANGE the base to not have a property at all (for example), and include a property ONLY in the derived class, you are not changing the base class behaviour "from inside" the derived class, you are changing the base class/derived class default behaviour. No more "Prop" in base class, Prop in derived class.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class has to implement the same interface as its base class - having a public setter be inaccessible from a derived class would break polymorphism.

If Prop needs to be inaccessible to clients, but you need to be able to set its value from within the class itself, you could declare it as:

```
public virtual int Prop { get; protected set; }
```

There probably isn't a single answer to this question, as it depends on the model for your specific application. If some derived classes need to allow writes to this property, but others don't, you could either throw an exception on an invalid write and handle it at run time, or perhaps implement the property using a protected backing field and only a getter, and then add a derived class that provides a SetProp() method for those classes that need it.

```
public class Base
{
    protected int prop;
    public virtual int Prop { get { return prop; } }
}

public class WriteableBase : Base
{
    public virtual void SetProp(int prop) { this.prop = prop; }
}
```

Comment: Using this approach, the OP could choose which class to use as the base class, so he could use the writeable base for everything except where he wants to restrict access.

Answer (score -1):

I think it´s not possible to get compiler-error in this case. Imagine further you´d declare `obj` not as `Derived` but as `Base = new Derived()`, how should compiler know which property to infer. So all you can do is to throw an exception during runtime within the derived setter telling that setting this property isn´t allowed fir this type.

```
class Base
{
    public virtual int Prop { get; protected set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override int Prop { 
        get { return 1; } 
        protected set {throw NotSupportedException();}  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why throw on a "protected" set?

Comment: @Jauch Because also "trusted" (meaning derived) features may cause errors? Or is the question why the property is protected rather then public? In the latter case the answer is because it uses the same access-modifier as the base-implementation (could ofc. also be public, but why should it?)

Comment: No. The question is more like, in an auto-property, if the set is protected, meaning that it will not be set outside the class, why to change the behaviour of the class? Just do not use it on the derived class. There is no need to add it and throw an exception. Unless you want to make sure that another programer will not make use of it accidentally, but it will be able to use the base set anyway, so, this will not help much, I think

Answer (score -3):

When compiling, C# transforms the getter and setter to individual methods (get_Prop and set_Prop). 
Your code only implements the `get` in the Derived class, and the `set`remains that of the base class.

If this is your desired behavior, I don't find it to be wrong.

If you are trying to hide the setter in the Derived class, there is no elegant way to do it, so throwing an NotSupportedException is a solution.

```
    class Base
    {
        public virtual int Prop { get; set; }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public override int Prop { get { return 1; } set { throw new NotSupportedException();}}
    }
```

Comment: This will not even compile as you cannot change the access modifier when overriding.

Comment: I had to test that as I didn't think you could do it. It fails to compile with the error 'cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member', which makes sense.

Comment: my bad. so, throwing an NotSupportedException might be the way to go. Editing my answer.